# Usage of "I am agreeably disappointed in"

Tags: phrase-usage

[(From *The Wrecker* by Robert Louis Stevenson and Lloyd Osbourne, Chapter XXII, published 1892)](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Chapter_22)

Passage 341

> The press of work was still at its highest when quarter-day approached. Norris was now raised to a position of some trust; at his discretion, trains were stopped or forwarded at the dangerous cornice near North Clifton; and he found in this responsibility both terror and delight. The thought of the seventy-five pounds that would soon await him at the lawyer's, and of his own obligation to be present every quarter-day in Sydney, filled him for a little with divided councils. Then he made up his mind, walked in a slack moment to the inn at Clifton, ordered a sheet of paper and a bottle of beer, and wrote, explaining that he held a good appointment which he would lose if he came to Sydney, and asking the lawyer to accept this letter as an evidence of his presence in the colony, and retain the money till next quarter-day. The answer came in course of post, and was not merely favourable but cordial. “Although what you propose is contrary to the terms of my instructions,” it ran, “I willingly accept the responsibility of granting your request. I should say **I am agreeably disappointed in your behaviour**. My experience has not led me to found much expectations on gentlemen in your position.”

Is the phrase "I am agreeably disappointed in your behaviour" common nowadays or is it obsolete - is it an understatement or is it a quirky jest?

Comment: I don't suppose it was ever common. It's an [oxymoron](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oxymoron).

Comment: **Please note: Not everything people say or write has been previously spoken or written". Thank goodness. If this were not the case, we don't even need to complain about AI because it will all already have been done.

Comment: _Nothing_ in this book is "common nowadays!

Comment: The giveaway is the next sentence: "My experience has not led me to found much expectations on gentlemen in your position." So it shows us that it corresponds to "**I am positively surprised**". And it's just a quirky way of saying it, perhaps to lend extra character, personality to the speaker; And it's totally old fashioned. Nowadays you would not risk of using such a negative word like "disappointment" to express positivity; in today's world a negative word like "disappointment" would immediately invoke negative connotations, and perhaps could never be percieved as "cordial".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the meanings of **disappoint** is to belie expectation. Since not all expectation is hopeful, and since the lawyer had indeed expected worse "from gentlemen in [his] position" and  had learned not to *depend* on them, not to "found" his expectations on them, the upshot in this instance is an *agreeable* form of disappointment. He is happy to say he had expected worse but was wrong.

In the 19th century, *especially in legal contexts*, the verb **disappoint** could mean to undo something, such as a will, or a plan, and developed the sense to undo or thwart a normal or expected course, or to run counter to expectation, and it could be used without the sense of emotional dejection that accompanies the use of the word nowadays.

Stevenson's lawyer is using the word as a lawyer might have used it in the 19th century

Nowadays, *disappointment* is used 99.44% of the time in the sense of having one's *hopes* unfulfilled.

Here's an attestion from *The Autobiography of Adin Ballou* (Lowell, Mass, 1896).

> ... I am also **happily disappointed** in the place. Those who have spoken against this city have misrepresented it. It is superior to Boston.

Here are a couple of attestations from 1875,  testimony given before the *GENERAL ASSEMBLY OF ILLINOIS, AT ITS TWENTY-NINTH SESSION*.

> In what respect are you disappointed in his or her progress since he or she came to the institution?
>
> In no respect are we in the least disappointed but on the contrary found the improvement beyond our expectation for which we are very grateful to you and your noble institution... In his personal appearance and his regard for cleanliness and his idea of things and places also in his dressing and undressing of bimself in which he has improved more than we expected, so that we are **[gladly disappointed](https://%3Ca%20href=%22https://books.google.com/books?id=7uNHAQAAMAAJ&newbks=0&dq=%22happily%20disappointed%22&pg=RA5-PA48&source=bookclip&ci=47%2C1187%2C931%2C415%22%3E%3Cimg%20src=%22https://books.google.com/books/content?id=7uNHAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA5-PA48&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&bul=1&sig=ACfU3U1jGsaCoY9-1sN9r-XGulF7vV1rhw&ci=47%2C1187%2C931%2C415&edge=0%22/%3E%3C/a%3E)** in the progress he has made ...

> ... I am indeed very **[happily disappointed](https://%3Ca%20href=%22https://books.google.com/books?id=7uNHAQAAMAAJ&newbks=0&dq=%22happily%20disappointed%22&pg=RA5-PA49&source=bookclip&ci=47%2C1089%2C923%2C112%22%3E%3Cimg%20src=%22https://books.google.com/books/content?id=7uNHAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA5-PA49&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&bul=1&sig=ACfU3U3WVRRsMER6Tcr_0AkDnP8-A_7ogQ&ci=47%2C1089%2C923%2C112&edge=0%22/%3E%3C/a%3E)** for she has made greater progress than I ever thought she would be capable of making ...

And here's one from the introduction to *The Complete Poetical Works of Robert Burns... with A Life of the Author*, James Currie, ed. (Philadelphia, 1844)

> The sense of his poverty and of the approaching dis tress of his infant family pressed heavily on Burns as he lay on the bed of death. Yet he alluded to his indigence at times with something approaching to his wonted gaiety. What business said he to Dr Maxwell, who attended him with the utmost zeal, has a physician to waste his time on me? I am a poor pigeon not worth plucking. Alas I have not feather enough upon me to carry me to my grave And when his reason was lost in delirium his ideas ran in the same melancholy train. The horrors of a jail were continually present to his troubled imagination and produced the most affecting exclamations.
>
> On the death of Burns the inhabitants of Dumfries and its neighbourhood opened a subscription for the support of his wife and family. The subscription was extended to other parts of Scotland and of England also particularly London and Liverpool. By this means a sum was raised amounting to seven hundred pounds and thus the widow and children were rescued from immediate distress and the most melancholy of the forebodings of Burns **happily disappointed**.

Comment: Please explain the downvote. I'm finding anonymous downvotes so effing tiresome. Have the courtesy to say what's wrong.

Comment: No downvote from me, but if I understand the context, I'm not sure this is the right reading. I think the lawyer offered Norris a job and Norris turned it down. I don't think the lawyer is saying that he _hoped_ Norris would refuse, but simply that he's not too torn up about it and can totally understand Norris's decision. Also, I think the legal sense, even though this is a lawyer, isn't useful as a meaning here.

Comment: If one thinks "disappointed" *must* be accompanied by at least some tinge of dejection, the lawyer's phrase "agreeably disappointed" will seem oxymoronic --  or the word "agreeably" itself will have to be twisted to mean "not too disagreeably" as you have done with  "not too torn up about it". But **disappointed** could refer to an experience that simply ran counter to expectation, and there need not be any tinge of dejection about it, certainly if what was expected was not hoped for.  I think the lawyer is playing with the word as he is aware of the colloquial and non-collloquial usages.

Comment: In my opinion it means something like "I am agreeably surprised at. . ." or "I am pleasantly surprised at . . .". I took "disappointed" to be an understatement.

Comment: @philphil  "Pleasantly surprised" is a decent substitute.  If you firmly expected the worst and your expectations were "disappointed", the experience would have an element of surprise and an element of pleasantness.

Answer (score 0):

"I am agreeably disappointed in your behaviour" was never a common phrase and only makes sense in context. It means that he is disappointed in the other's behaviour but, as this confirms his expectations, is happy to be so. You would never (now or then) use this phrase in isolation except for literary effect. It would just be confusing.

Comment: I think it means that the lawyer was obliged to say that he was officially 'disappointed' in Norris' behaviour, but he unofficially was pleased at it because it showed a degree of gentlemanly behaviour not usual in men in Norris' position. Like a teacher might say that he is disappointed that you refuse to name a boy who has misbehaved, but who is quietly glad that you refuse to betray a friend.

Comment: @Michael, I think I agree with you. The last sentance seems to support my interpretation but the preceding text supports yours more.

Comment: I would agree with Michael Harvey. The lawyer is "cordial". And I think he believes Norris's behavior shows a forthrightness and sense of responsibility that runs counter to his expectations: "My experience has not led me to found much expectations on gentlemen in your position.”"